# How to enable development mode or display errors in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hosting

When I browse the site I get:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

as I've seen its a `500.html` file, so its some internal server error, but how can I make display those errors?

I've tried this:

1) putting `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'development'`in environment.rb, but nothing happened

2) `config.log_level = :any`, then looked at the production.log, but there is not 500 errors

Or what I need to write in the 500.html to see errors?, or just display it no matter how.

Comment: send your background logs so we understand the where error comes

Comment: where can i find them?, i have only production.log - file

Comment: rails s - created a new folder application within my main application, i've refreshed the broswer and what now?, i don't see any logs in my terminal

Comment: emmm.. i've typed rail s - rails is creating a new app in a new folder, how can i start or restart the server?, touch tmp/restart.txt - dont work, script restart - the same

Comment: i have only the production.log file, is there a way that i can generate a log of errors?, or how can i switch to development mode in rails 2.3?

Comment: i've readed your email, now i've tried to start my ruby on rails 2.3 version, and i get this Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.

Answer (score 4):

Your log files (wherever they're written) should contain your errors.

If you still like to view the errors in the browser you could change the following in your environment/production.rb (but consider it as a temporary work-around). Make sure to switch it back.

`config.consider_all_requests_local = true`

Comment: i've changed it to true, but I still don't see any error messages, it renders me the 500.html - some internal server error..., i've looked for 500 -error in the log/production.log - i didn't find it..

Comment: Your sever might be writing log files elsewhere (not necessarily <app>/log/production.log). What's your sever setup?

Comment: in what file i can see that setup?

Comment: In addition to this, you can also try `config.action_controller.perform_caching = false` in production.rb